# Split Spring Boot fat jar to two jars (app / libs)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

To optimise Docker layers, I am trying to split our 30M Spring Boot fat jar into the 2M app.jar and 28M libs.jar.

I can use exploded mode, but I prefer using 2 jars, because it simplifies a few things, such as deployments, scripts etc. In particular the fat jar is more easily and intuitively executed with `java -jar`, as opposed to the more cumbersome `java org.springframework.boot.loader....Launcher`.

My problem is that the moment I separate the libs out, I can't get the Launcher to find them. In either jar or exploded mode (with two dirs) - I keep getting

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/odoro/common/api/ServiceType
    at com.odoro.sync.service.Application.main(Application.java:14)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.odoro.common.api.ServiceType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I get this in all the following cases:

```
# java -jar app.jar -cp ../lib.jar

# java -cp .:../lib org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

# java -Dloader.path=../lib org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [the Spring Boot thin launcher](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher) is what you're looking for.